# Multi href in url

Tags: php, mysqli

Im working on a school project and i want to pass more then one value thru the url.
The page show more then one user from the Database.

This is what im trying to do so far, and i get a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 79

This is the code im trying to use

```
<?php

//loop over alle reservationerne og display dem i en table, hvis de ikke er tomme
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($num>0)
    {
        while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            echo "
        <div class='table-card'> 
            <div class='table-num'>
                <div class='table'><a>Bord " .$result["Bord"]."</a></div>
                <div class='fjern'><a OnClick=\"return confirm('Er du sikker på du vil slette reservationen');\" href='admin.php?id=$result['ID']&navn=$result['Navn']'>X</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class='table-info'>
```

And this is the part giving me trouble

```
<div class='fjern'><a OnClick=\"return confirm('Er du sikker på du vil slette reservationen');\" href='admin.php?id=$result['ID']&navn=$result['Navn']'>X</a></div>
```

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Tjek om brugeren er logget ind, hvis ikke redirect dem til login siden
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

//connect til databasen
require_once "config.php";

//Få fat på id så vi kan delete bestemte reservationer



    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
    
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $navn=$_GET['Navn'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `reject`(`ID`, `Navn`) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $navn);
    $stmt->execute();

    $delete = "DELETE FROM reservation WHERE ID=$id;";
    $svar = $link->query($delete);

}

    //setup så vi kan vise reservationerne
$select ="select * from reservation ORDER BY Klok";
$query = $link->query($select);
$link -> close();

?>
```

Comment: use just one `&` not two `&&` and an `=` so `?id=$result['ID']&navn=$result['Navn']`

Comment: Then show a bit more code so we know if you are in a PHP block or a html block and whats quote to use etc

Comment: Just gave that a tried that and im getting the same error

Comment: edited the post now to show all the important php

Comment: Use [heredoc strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to have less headache escaping your quotes while interpolating variables into strings. `echo <<<FOO ... whatever, <a href="?name={$name}">let's link</a> FOO;`. Also, using curly brackets helps. `"whatever {$result['ID']} so."` (_"...quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax"_, per the manual page above.)

Comment: adding the curly brackets seems to have done the trick.

Comment: tho im getting a undefined array error on the value "navn" saying its NULL

Answer (score 1):

Adding the curly brackets seems to have done the trick now :)

```
<div class='fjern'><a OnClick=\"return confirm('Er du sikker på du vil slette reservationen');\" href='admin.php?id={$result['ID']}&navn={$result['Navn']}'>X</a></div>
```

Thx for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div class='table-card'> 
        <div class='table-num'>
            <div class='table'>
                <a>Bord $result[Bord]</a>
            </div>
            <div class='fjern'>
                <a OnClick='return confirm(\"Er du sikker på du vil slette reservationen\"');'                
                    href='admin.php?id=$result[ID]&navn=$result[Navn]'>X</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class='table-info'>";
```

Will generate

```
<div class='table-card'> 
        <div class='table-num'>
            <div class='table'>
                <a>Bord xxxxxxx</a>
            </div>
            <div class='fjern'>
                <a OnClick='return confirm("Er du sikker på du vil slette reservationen"');'                
                    href='admin.php?id=33&navn=ddddd'>X</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class='table-info'>
```

If I fake up an results array like this

```
$result = [ "ID"=> 33, "Navn" => 'ddddd', "Bord" => 'xxxxxxx'];
```